# How Do Remote Exploits Work?

Tags: assembly, exploit

How is it that malicious hackers can gain remote access using exploits such as buffer overflows?  I've been following The Art of Exploitation book, yet I'm having issues wrapping my head around certain subjects.  I'm assuming that the only thing that a listening program is allowed to take from anyone remotely is program arguments?  So any remote code they want the program to execute must be put into the program via argument, which then exists in memory.  Then you must make the program return execution to this point in memory, correct?

So basically, if all the  previous theory is correct, I am wondering how people make exploits that almost work every time considering compiler optimizations vary from system to system (plus address randomization, etc.), and how if all the exploit is doing is calling a program with a generated buffer, could you not literally exploit programs by calling programs with a copy/pasted string consisting of exploit code (with nop sled then shellcode or whatever)?

Answer (score 0):

If we speak in general way about exploits, coding bugs or a poor controlled inputs, may be a source of a security vulnerabilities, all what you said is true, but you missed the root cause of vulnerabilities.

> Then you must make the program return execution to this point in memory, correct?

This is the normal way of use, but exploiting is to use program in a malicious way not as "nice" users do.
Please check this wiki article to have an idea about [exploiting BOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow#Exploitation).
Other great explanation with [c programming](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/secure.html).